# Blank cell in excel with iF FUNCTION

Tags: javascript, excel, if-statement, prediction, iif-function

I'm trying to make a World Cup 2018 Excel sheet prediction for me and my friends.

I have succeeded to make all the functions for example -
I have one table that presents the real scores which are connected with a function to the other members prediction table.

The only problem that I have now that if someone predicts a tie (1-1) and the game didn't happen yet, so that means the cells are empty - then it gives him a 1 point for guessing true... like 1-1 equals to blank - blank.

This is my function so far:

```
 =VALUE(IF(AND(E9="",J9=""),"0",IF(AND(E9>F9,J9>K9),"1",IF(AND(F9>E9,K9>J9),"1",IF(AND(E9=F9,J9=K9),"1","")))))
```

The prediction is only for tie/win/lose it's not related to specific score.

How can I prevent blank cells from being equal to tie?

Edit :
[Image for example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l66eU.jpg)

Now if they didn't predict correctly then instead of "0" there is an error...

Comment: For what reason are you using `VALUE`? Can you not remove all `""` from your statements and just use numbers.

Comment: I Use value because I have SUM function on top all of the predictions for each player. I found that SUM can't treat "1" which represent "true" to be counted as a number so in order for that be a number I needed to add the Value statement.

Comment: Instead of using "0" and "1" just put the number - IF() will handle those fine, so the first two ifs become : VALUE(IF(AND(E9="",J9=""),0,IF(AND(E9>F9,J9>K9),1, rest of expression

Answer (score 0):

Do a test to see if the guessing cells are blank first (I assumed A1 and B1 for this example), then do your function, so:

```
=IF(OR(A1="",B1=""),"","your_function")
```

See:
[image]

Edit: re comment,
The OR() function checks to see if EITHER guess cell is blank, if one is blank then it assumes the guess is not complete, obviously if both are blank - again the guess is not complete, if both are not blank it does your function.

Comment: Hi it works!
=IF(OR(E8="",F8=""),"0",VALUE(IF(AND(E8="",J8=""),"0",IF(AND(E8>F8,J8>K8),"1",IF(AND(F8>E8,K8>J8),"1",IF(AND(E8=F8,J8=K8),"1",""))))))

Thanks so much (:

can I have a small explanation why i needed the OR here? I tried the same thing with AND and NA and it didn't work, for example

AND(A1=NA,B1=NA),"",Value....

Comment: Hi i have now noticed that there is a different problem, if he didnt predict correctly then instead of having "0"/"" there is an error #Value!...

Comment: I would not put the 0 zero in "" as it may not then behave correctly as a first step. After that, you may need to provide some actual data so we can see what happens.